# Browser not loading font file (woff / woff2) when loading website

Tags: c#, css, iis, razor, font-face

I have a partial razor page in which I define a `font-family` and a `font-face` for a font called *Futura Bk BT Book*.

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Font))
{
    <text>
        @@font-face{
            font-family: "'Futura Bk BT Book'";
                src: url(@Url.Content("~/Assets/fonts/Futura Bk BT Book.woff2")) format("woff2"),
                     url(@Url.Content("~/Assets/fonts/Futura Bk BT Book.woff")) format("woff");
        }
        html{
            font-family: @Html.Raw(Model.Font);
        }
    </text>
}
```

When I access this page, the browser is not loading the linked woff files and instead uses the next font given in `@Model.Font` which is *Arial*.

[image: screenshot from browser dev tools]

When I try to access the font file via the url I get by `@Url.Content("~/Assets/fonts/Futura Bk BT Book.woff2")` then I can download the file. So it seems that the file is accessible and only the browser doesn't try to load it.

I'm using C# 7.3 and IIS 10.

I'm glad about any hint and can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem. It was a problem with our build pipeline not rebuilding the css file. So no problem with the functionality above at all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, IIS does not need a mime type added for WOFF it will need one for WOFF2.
So you can try to add the mime type in IIS, modify your Web.Config as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: Is `application/font-woff2` right or should it be `font/woff2`? When I use your suggestion, it's always set to the second value when rebuilding the project.